# Append specific file in many paths with a line

Tags: bash, scripting

For some reasons I have copied a php.ini file to all of the home directories of my users
Example:

```
/home/user1/php.ini
/home/user2/php.ini
/home/user3/php.ini
```

chown of any user's home folder is the same as the user:
example:

```
/home/user1/   is owned by user1 and group is set to user1
```

I want to append all of the php.ini files with specific line like:

```
open_basedir=/home/xxxxx:/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi:/tmp
```

and instead of xxxxxx I want to have the owner of the related folder in which that php.ini is currently in.

How to automate this?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you going to identify those files? What about the `php.ini` file in `/home/user4` — is the list exhaustive or indicative, and are there any files that should be excluded (for example, is `/home/*/php.ini` too inclusive, or are there any other places to look)?  Are you going to be running as `root`?  If not, there will be problems; if so, you must be extremely careful to get it right first time.  You should really be showing what you've tried — or started to work with.  It is not dreadfully hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do as root :

```
cd /home
for user in */; do
    test -s /home/${user}php.ini || continue
    chown ${user%/}: /home/${user}php.ini
    echo "open_basedir=/home/${user%/}:/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi:/tmp" >> /home/${user}php.ini
done
```

Comment: The question says 'append'; I think you can assume the line is not there yet. You can still use `sed` — though `echo ... > /home/$user/php.ini` might be simpler.

Comment: Dear sputnick, Thank you for your answer. It seems great but as i already mentioned i have over 200 php.ini files in each user's main folder. How to define the /path/to/php.ini ?
I have have the list of paths to php.ini files. is it possible to give the list to the script as stdin

Comment: POST edited with your given PATH. I expect to be all in the same sub PATH for each users. If not, clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find` command:

```
cd /home
find . -name 'php.ini' -exec bash -c 'd="${1%/*}"; d="${d#*/}"; echo "open_basedir=/home/$d:/usr/local/etc/php5/cgi:/tmp" >> "$1"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: Dear friend i placed this script in /home directory and there result was one php.ini file in the /home directory and having many lines in it which are result of the echo command.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, it is fixed now.